# How to exit a console application when user type anything?

Tags: .net, vb.net, console, console-application

I have following VB.NET console application code:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim UserInfo As String = "Name: User1"

        System.Console.WriteLine(UserInfo)
        System.Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

How to exit the console application when user types anything?

**UPDATE**: This is the solution:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim UserInfo As String = "Name: User1"

        System.Console.WriteLine(UserInfo)
        System.Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `System.Console.ReadKey()` instead of `System.Console.ReadLine()`

Answer (score 3):

Use this one:

```
System.Console.ReadKey()
```

It will read a keystroke and return to code. If there is no more code after the `System.Console.ReadKey()` line then it will exit the console application.

You can check the value of keystroke being pressed by user and decide whether to do what in next action. You can exit the console application immediate using `Exit Sub`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
System.Console.ReadLine()
```

Use:

```
System.Console.ReadKey()
```

The former (your code) waits for the user to enter a line.

Comment: `Console.Read()` still waits until you press enter before it returns. You need `Console.ReadKey()` instead.